# How to set tint mode and tint color for compose vector icons programtically

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-vectordrawable

I had some vector icons that were converted from SVG and I need to customize the tint colors for them based on some conditions, I'm trying to change the tint color programmatically

```
Image(
        modifier = Modifier.size(128.dp),
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.icon_1),
        contentDescription = null,
        colorFilter =  ColorFilter.tint(Color.Red)
    )
```

it gave me the following result

[image: result]

also, When I tried to do it by using

```
Image(
    modifier = Modifier.size(128.dp),
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.icon_1),
    contentDescription = null,
    colorFilter =  ColorFilter.tint(Color.Red, blendMode = BlendMode.Multiply)
)
```

I got the same result as well. but, when I tried to change the icon tint from the XML file by adding

```
android:tint="@color/red"
android:tintMode="multiply"
```

it gave me the desired result correctly like the following

[image]

So how can I achieve the same result programmatically as I need to change the color programmatically to different colors based on some conditions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to fix it by using `blendMode = BlendMode.Modulate`

```
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier.size(128.dp),
        painter = painterResource(id = resultType.resId),
        contentDescription = null,
        colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(color = Color.Red, blendMode = BlendMode.Modulate) }
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Icon` instead of `Image`. The `Icon` function has a parameter to change the icon color:

```
Icon(
    modifier = Modifier.size(128.dp),
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.icon_1),
    contentDescription = null,
    tint = Color.Red,
)
```

Comment: It gave me the same result like the image